# How do I prevent browserify from including multiple versions of sub-dependencies?

Tags: browserify

In my front-end code, I use `require()` to pull in libraries which, in turn, depend on different versions of Underscore.js. As a result, when I use browserify to bundle everything together, the output contains multiple copies of Underscore. Is there a way to tell browserify that `require('underscore')` should always import a particular file?

As a demonstration of the problem, imagine I have the following dependencies:

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
  // Depends on underscore 1.7.0
  "backbone": "^1.1.2",

  // Depends on underscore 1.6.0
  "backbone.marionette": "^2.3.0"
}
```

In `main.js` I use both libraries:

```
// main.js
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
console.log("Hello, world!");
```

When I create a bundle, multiple versions of Underscore are included:

```
PS> browserify main.js -o out.js
PS> findstr _.VERSION out.js
  _.VERSION = '1.7.0';
  _.VERSION = '1.6.0';
```

([I created a GitHub repository with a more complete example](https://github.com/brantb/browserify-duplicate-libs). Clone it and run `npm install && npm test` to see it in action)

I tried adding a `browser` section to my `package.json` like the following, but it didn't seem to have any effect:

```
// package.json
"browser": {
  "underscore": "./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"
}
```

I understand why `npm` installs duplicate dependencies (and it makes sense to do it this way for server-side code) but what's the correct way to deal with this when using browserify?

Answer (score 10):

There is a duplicate detection in Browserify that should avoid loading the same version more than once. However, if your `node_modules` tree contains multiple copies of the same module, this detection might (should?) fail.

The solution that I'm using is to dedupe the package structure with npm:

```
npm dedupe
```

This will only leave unavoidable dupes in your dependency tree and it will log a warning about those dupes so that you can double check.